# what's the universal covering group of general linear group $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ and $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, covering-spaces

Because the general linear group is not simply connected, they must be able to be covered by some simply connected Lie group. But I cannot imagine which Lie group with same dimension can cover  $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ and $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: It's usually just called "The universal cover of $GL$".

Comment: It is not a matrix group

Comment: @MikeMiller So it's not a matrix Lie group? In which condition a Lie group's universal covering group is still a matrix Lie group?

Comment: @PeterFranek In which condition a Lie group's universal covering group is still a matrix Lie group?

Comment: $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ has two diffeomorphic connected components. The identity component $GL^+(n, \mathbb{R})$ deformation retracts onto $SO(n)$. For $n \geq 3$, $\pi_1(SO(n)) = \mathbb{Z}_2$ so its universal cover is a two-fold cover called the [spin group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group) $Spin(n)$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I don't think so. $dim\ Spin(n)< dim\ GL^+ (n,R)$

Comment: @user34669: $Spin(n)$ covers $SO(n)$ not $GL^+(n, \mathbb{R})$. My comment doesn't answer your question, but if you only care about the universal cover up to homotopy equivalence, it is the simplest description I am aware of.

Comment: @user34669 I don't know in general. This might be another interesting question.